# What is the Sybase analog to Sql Server's BEGIN TRANSACTION ... ROLLBACK or COMMIT TRANSACTION?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sybase

I have googled and searched the Sybase docs but I do not think I am asking the right questions.

Let me also preface this by saying I am in no way a DB guru.

In Sql Server I know I can encompass a block of SQL with

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
...
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

or

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
...
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

How do I implement the same functionality in Sybase?

Comment: I think it is the same thing in Sybase

Comment: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/X315689.htm

Comment: As SQL Server was originally based off of Sybase, trying what works in SQL Server is a good start.

Comment: @Parado I honestly don't know.  I have to use a proprietary piece of software our company created to connect to the DB.  I'm trying to find out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sybase ASE and SQL Server have a shared heritage, so both use Transact SQL (T-SQL) as their flavor of SQL.  The BEGIN, ROLLBACK and COMMIT commands are the same.